# PL/SQL RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR parameter question

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and I do not completely understand error-code parameter of the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR.

In the documentation it says `The error_number is a negative integer with the range from -20999 to -20000`.  But that does not explain if I can pick random number or is there a system to it.
Also I am wondering if I can reuse the same numbers in different functions when calling RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR? Or will that number be used somewhere to identify that particular error?

I also was looking at the procedure someone wrote and wondering why didn't they just pass `SQLCODE` to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR instead of taking random number like `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(l_err_code, 'Record already exists!');`

I got an impression that one only uses integers -20999 to -20000 for the user-defined errors, not existing ones.

```
PROCEDURE insert_record
(v_row IN OUT TABLE1%ROWTYPE) IS

 l_err_code NUMBER;
 l_err_message VARCHAR(200);
 BEGIN 


    INSERT INTO TABLE1 ....
      RETURNING id INTO V_row.id;

 EXCEPTION      
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
       l_err_code := SQLCODE;  
       l_err_message  := 'Insert Error: ' - ' || SQLERRM;   

       ...logging error here

      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Record already exists!');    
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    l_err_code := SQLCODE;
    l_err_message  := 'Insert Error: ' - ' || SQLERRM;   

     --- loggin error here

    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, l_err_message);      

END insert_record;
```

Would it make sense to modify above function as follows?:

```
PROCEDURE insert_record
(v_row IN OUT TABLE1%ROWTYPE) IS

 l_err_code NUMBER;
 l_err_message VARCHAR(200);
 BEGIN 


    INSERT INTO TABLE1 ....
      RETURNING id INTO V_row.id;

 EXCEPTION      
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
       l_err_code := SQLCODE;  
       l_err_message  := 'Record already exists!';   

       ...logging error here

      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(l_err_code, l_err_message);    
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    l_err_code := SQLCODE;
    l_err_message  := 'Insert Error: ' - ' || SQLERRM;   

     --- loggin error here

    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(l_err_code, l_err_message);      

END insert_record;
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could answer those questions for me or point me to some documentation clarifying those.

Comment: By the way, keep in mind that Oracle APEX does sometimes raise exceptions in this range, so be careful if you try to use SQLCODE to refer to a particular application error. Personally I tend to use just -20000 ("user error") and -20001 ("system error") and embed more useful information into the error message itself. YMMV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` only accepts numbers in the range -20999 to -20000 for its `error_code` parameter. Within the -20999 to -20000 you can use the error numbers however you want, without restriction. Any "organization" of the numbers is up to you.  If you pass a number outside that range a *different* exception is raised - `ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of -xxxxx is out of range`. For example:

```
BEGIN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-54321, 'This is not a valid error code');
END;
```

causes the exceptions

```
ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of -54321 is out of range
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

to be raised. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c6794e069c2940717652adec791e905a)

Note that because SQLCODE values generated by Oracle are *always* outside the range allowed for `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` you cannot pass SQLCODEs to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR or you'll get the same ORA-21000 exception raised, which rather defeats the purpose of passing SQLCODE to `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`. The correct way to re-raise a system-defined exception such as DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX is to use the no-argument version of the RAISE statement. For example, let's rewrite your code slightly:

```
PROCEDURE insert_record
(v_row IN OUT TABLE1%ROWTYPE) IS

 l_err_code NUMBER;
 l_err_message VARCHAR(200);
 BEGIN 


    INSERT INTO TABLE1 ....
      RETURNING id INTO V_row.id;

 EXCEPTION      
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
       l_err_code := SQLCODE;  
       l_err_message  := 'Record already exists!';   

       -- log error here

       -- Now, re-raise the exception so an outer handler can deal with it.
       -- Note that there's no way to include a new error message in this case.

       RAISE;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
      l_err_code := SQLCODE;
      l_err_message  := 'Insert Error: ' - ' || SQLERRM;   

       --- log error here

      -- Now, re-raise the exception so an outer handler can deal with it
      RAISE;    
END insert_record;
```

You can use other error numbers by creating `EXCEPTION` variables, assigning exception numbers to them using the `EXCEPTION_INIT` pragma, and then using the `RAISE` statement to raise these exceptions. For example,

```
DECLARE
  my_exception EXCEPTION;

  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(my_exception, -54321);
BEGIN
  RAISE my_exception;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN my_exception THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('my_exception caught!');
END;
```

which produces the output

```
my_exception caught!
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f74d47a51d87314d440cb4e74462aa9b)

`PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT` allows values in the range -10000000 to -1 except for -1403. 100 is also allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You can pick any number in that range for your own application errors.  It's certainly possible to create a real mess with duplicates numbers and subtly different error text messages.  Error numbers you define could be errors that are business logic errors not known possible errors such as too many rows.

There is a [really good detailed explanation](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/error-management) here and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-exceptions-and-rules) by Steven Feurstein where he outlines the proper scope.

Error handling is worth spending some time thinking about and leads to some abstract questions such as:

- can the application carry on processing if there is an error?
- If not then you need to stop processing as you don't want an incomplete or partial transaction processed
- what information do you need to trace where an error occurred?  (usually, package name, function/procedure name, line number, offending code, parameters in use when the exception was thrown.

In my experience most applications cannot and should not continue processing a transaction when an exception of any kind is called.  At that time you want to log all the details to a table, halt further processing and have the application redirect to a "sorry, an error occurred" page.

For the code above I would remove the When Others.  You have errors that you know could occur such as too many values.  You want to log details and stop processing.  For unknown errors I would rather have the error bubble up from the procedure or function call than seeing it possibly erroneously classed as a known error.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that codes between 20000 and 20999 are for user-defined errors. There is no need to force such an error code into a condition/response that is already defined by Oracle unless you need to add some other essential level of detail to the error handling.

Comment: but can I pass SQLCODE to the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR when I want to return an erro to the application?

Comment: Yes. That is standard practice. Check these links for more info from the PL/SQL Master:

https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/error-management

http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/03/nine-good-to-knows-about-plsql-error.html

http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2017/02/now-not-to-handle-exceptions.html

Comment: But above it was mentioned that passing SQLCODEs to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR will generate ORA-21000 exception since those are ouside of allowable range

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. You done need to use RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR, just RAISE. RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR is just for your custom errors.